# totals for a measure with LOG10 are wrong

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot, excel-2016

I have a table 'Range' with strings in a [node] column. 
I created a [measure] for a pivot that calculates a percentage of occurrences of each string.

```
measure = COUNTA(Range[node])/CALCULATE(COUNTA(Range[node]);ALL(Range[node]))
```

This works very well and the total of the percentage =1 as it should:

```
+-------+---------------+---------+
| node  | count of node | measure |
+-------+---------------+---------+
| a     |             1 | 0.007   |
| b     |            22 | 0.162   |
| c     |           103 | 0.757   |
| d     |            10 | 0.074   |
| Total |           136 | 1.000   |
+-------+---------------+---------+
```

But when I want to get a LOG10 of the measure, values are fine, but the total changes to 0.

When I use:

```
measure = LOG10((COUNTA(Range[node])/CALCULATE(COUNTA(Range[node]);ALL(Range[node]))))
```

I get:

```
+-------+---------------+--------------+
| node  | count of node |   measure    |
+-------+---------------+--------------+
| a     |             1 | -2.134       |
| b     |            22 | -0.791       |
| c     |           103 | -0.120701684 |
| d     |            10 | -1.133538908 |
| Total |           136 | 0            |
+-------+---------------+--------------+
```

What should I do to get the correct Total of -4.179?

Comment: Yes, log10(1.0) == 0, it works.  Don't apply the formula to the Total row, you only need to sum the previous ones.

Comment: Yes, I only need the total of the rows, that's what I thought Subtotals in Pivots do, don't they? If not, how do I do it automatically in a Pivot?

Comment: Is the total row something in your sheet that you're including in the pivot or are you showing the output of the pivot. Because by default, if you just put the rows up to but not including the total row, the pivot table by default does exactly that and shows -4.179

Comment: Not sure I understand here. I have a table of rows with strings, I create a pivot out of these, add the only field in the rows, create the measure described, the total automatically appears, but shows 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the sum of the logs then only copy your measure formula into rows a-d and make the total the sum of those 4 measures; as it is, you're calculating 136/136 to get 1, not adding 0.007+0.162... to get 1

So in the LOG10 example, the 0 appears because LOG10(136/136) = LOG10(1) which by definition is 0

Note that adding logs of numbers corresponds to finding the log of the **product** of all the entries,

i.e. log10( (1/136) x (22/136) x (103/136) x (10/136) ) = -4.179

As in log(a x b) = log(a) + log(b)

Maybe that's what you want but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, thanks for pointing out I can LOG the product, but I actually need a bit more complicated calculation for my measure - information entropy, so I need to SUM values like P(x)*LOG(P(x)). Therefore, I think I need to do the LOG by row, not only with the total. Could this be done?